# Visual Studio Web App that keeps on running at the Server even without Client to monitor time log

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, web-applications

I am currently creating a Web App that receives updates using GET methods from ESP8266. The ESP8266 sends updates every 5 minutes. These "updates" puts a time log in the database through the Web App. The Web App then checks if the ESP8266 is still "ON" by checking the time log if the ESP8266 has sent data within 5 minutes. However, this only works if the Web App is open on a browser.

Is there a way that even if the Web App is not accessed by any client (browser), it can still check if the ESP8266 has logged within that 5 minute window? I am thinking that it is freely running in the Server and continuously checking if the ESP8266 is still "ON". Because if the ESP8266 is turned OFF it will not be able to send data to the Web App anymore and and the Sever would automatically update the database that the ESP8266 is OFF.

Comment: Sounds like you might need a windows service (or equivalent) running on the machine to do that kind of work for you, as a webapp will only be active when it's asked to do something (i.e. when a client accesses it).

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on doing this? I'm currently using visual studio. Can Visual Studio do such kind of program that would work in parallel with my webapp? @jonc

Comment: absolutely. You'd create a separate solution for a Windows Service (there is a template in VS to create this), and code the service to poll the time log to see if the ESP8266 has sent data. This would mean you won't need the web app to be open in a browser as it will happen in the background.

Comment: @jonc - Thanks for the tip. I guess that is the solution that I'm looking for.

Comment: No problem. You might find these sites useful for creating windows services - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k985bc9(v=vs.110).aspx and http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/naresh.avari/develop-and-install-a-windows-service-in-c-sharp/ (which refers to using timers, so might be almost ideal for your use case!). Good luck!